# 2^N Combinaisons with Integers (Kernel), how to generate them?

Tags: java, algorithm, math, for-loop

(Merry Christmas btw ^^)

Here is my problem (in JAVA) but it's definitely an algorithmic problem and I don't know how to solve it :/ 
So here it is, with an example (just for information, all my calculs are in Binary, so 1+1 = 0)

let's name variables:

```
  N : the number of elements in kernel.
  M : the length of an element in the kernel.

  int[][] Kernel: 

            ....
            i   : 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 0  (length = M)
            i+1 : 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 1  (length = M)
            ....
            N   : ....
```

My goal with theses things, is to generate all the possible combinaison (so 2^N elements)
and I want to generate them.
By generate I mean exactly this :

```
    Result[0]     = 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
    Result[1]     = Kernel[0]
    Result[2]     = Kernel[1]
    ....
    Result[i]     = Kernel[i-1]
    Result[N-1]   = Kernel[N-2]

    Result[N]     = Kernel[0] + Kernel[1]
    Result[N+1]   = Kernel[0] + Kernel[2]
    Result[N+i]   = Kernel[0] + Kernel[i]
    Result[2N-1]  = Kernel[0] + Kernel[N-1]
    ....
    Result[I]     = Kernel[0] + Kernel[1] + Kernel[2]
    Result[I+1]   = Kernel[0] + Kernel[1] + Kernel[i]
    Result[I+J]   = Kernel[0] + Kernel[1] + Kernel[N-1]
    ....
    Result[2^N+1] = Kernel[0] + Kernel[1] + ... + Kernel[i] + ... + Kernel[N-1]
```

Here is what I already success to do, but it's not complete and I don't know how to generalize the calcul in order to work with any N...

```
public static int[][] combinaisons(int[][] kernel) {

    /* if the kernel is empty, there is no possible combinaison */
    if(kernel.length == 0) return kernel;

    /* We allocate the good number of space... */
    int[][] result = new int[(int) (Math.pow(2, noyau.length)+1)][];

    /* Every element in result has the same length as in kernel's elements. */
    for(int i = 0; i < resultat.length; i++) {
        result[i] = new int[kernel[0].length];
    }

    /* The first element of result has to be only 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 */
    for(int j = 0; j < kernel[0].length; j++) {
        result[0][j] = 0;
    }

    /* We rewrite the element of kernel because they are a part of the solution... */
    for(int i = 0; i < kernel.length; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < kernel[i].length; j++) {
            result[i+1][j] = kernel[i][j];
        }
    }


    /* 
       I managed to do it when it's the sum of only 2 elements, 
       but it has to be with 3, 4 ... N-1 :/ 
    */
    for(int i = 0; i < kernel.length; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < kernel[i].length; j++) {
            for(int k = i+1; k < kernel.length; k++) {

                result[k*kernel.length+i][j] = (kernel[i][j]+kernel[k][j])%2;

            }
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

---

Edit:

About an example, let's give this:

```
 N = 2 
 M = 4 
 Kernel: 
      0 1 1 0
      1 0 0 1 

In result I want: 
      0 0 0 0 
      0 1 1 0 
      1 0 0 1 
      1 1 1 1 (the sum of the 2 elements in Kernel)
```

So this is a simple example (quite particularly values, if you want bigger, just ask :) )

**Even if the array at the end seems to be VERY HUGE :) that's exactly what I want to generate (don't care about memory, it will for sure be okay)**

Comment: could you give a small example

Comment: You do realize that you'll run out of memory pretty quickly with this. You certainly can't have N > 31, and the bigger M is, the quicker you're going to run out of memory.

Comment: Well I totally agree with you @RealSkeptic, but N will never be higher 20. So the memory will be okay ;)

Comment: That looks like a problem, no matter how you do it. What is this for? Maybe we can help you find a way to do it without having to explicitly construct this enormous array. Also consider that you're calculating M-bit xors, if M is 64 or less you can save a lot of trouble.

Comment: About the example, let's give this: 

N = 2
M = 4

Kernel: 
    0 1 1 0 ; 
    1 0 0 1 ;
   

In result I want:
   0 0 0 0 ; 
   0 1 1 0 ; 
   1 0 0 1 ;
   1 1 1 1 ; (the sum of the 2 elements in Kernel)

So this is a simple example (quite particularly values, if you want bigger, just ask :) )

Comment: can you give a number example separated by spaces or lines of the binary output you are expecting??  I know what 2^n elements means but your arrays are not helping my understanding of your problem.  Generating 2^N can be done recursively very quickly.  what is the base and the end you want?

Comment: The context of this problem is as follow:

I play the game Lights-out http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lights_Out_(game)
And I figure out with a friend, that after some calculs, we see that all the combinaison of this kernel give us all the "possible solution" of this game :)

And I have after, an other function in order to find the optimal solution ;)

Comment: Is it important what order the 2^n combinations are listed in? Is it necessary to have 0 first, then the elements of kernel, then the sum of 2 elements of kernel, ...? If not then it's quite easy because you can just base the answer on the bit pattern of each of the first 2^n integers. However, I agree with RealSkeptic. You definitely do not want to create this massive array. Instead you want a method that takes Kernel and an int j and returns the combination at position j.

Comment: Please add all additional information requested *inside the question* using the `edit` button. Comments are not suitable for formatted information.

Comment: @pbabcdefp the order inside result doesn't matter, the only things that matter is : to have all the possible combinaison inside a result array.

Comment: Don't solve Lights Out this way. See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14169450/555045

Comment: @harold it's a modified Lights out, with N*M dimensions, and not necessary "everything shut down" at the end ;)

Comment: So you are trying to solve this Lights-Out game with an algorithm.  Ahh I see interesting, the way you are going about it is not going to work very well, since the game is a 5x5 grid you want a 5x5 2d array where 1 is on and 0 is off, then put in the contraints where if you switch from 1 to 0 or o to 1 all surrounding coordinates flip.  this is easy to do with the correct looping.  then you just have to program the recursive solver

Comment: @ValentinMontmirail that doesn't really matter, that's just an other XOR

Comment: @DavidColer it's already working with this algorithm, We just figure out with a friend, that all the combinaison inside the kernel gives us all the possible solutions, and we want to find the optimal one by generate all the possible... :)


harolds, I agree, but still :/ I don't know how to put this in place, how to XOR every combinaisons ? :/

Comment: The problem you are dealing with is millions of possible working combinations, what you can do is keep track of the moves as you go through solving with an int incrementer per move, and store the lowest moves array into an arraylist or something, and go through all possible solutions if you find a lower move solution replace the array with the new move array replace int with new low move count and keep going until you do all solutions.  You can also add in a counter for the current moves and if it goes over the low move count discard solution and move on to next iteration

Comment: @DavidColer, well it's not necessary a problem, because N will be for sure small (if very unlucky, I can go until [15-20]), but most of the time, it's like [3 - 7] so it will be okay with the memory :)

Optimisation of the code will come after, but it's even a logical problem, I still don't know how to go through every possibility :D that's the aim of my question ^^.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am going to use `boolean[][]` instead of `int[][]`. `0` means `false`, `1` means `true`.

```
public static boolean[][] combinations(boolean kernel[][]) {
    int n = kernel.length;
    int m = kernel[0].length;
    int p = 1 << n;
    boolean[][] temp = new boolean[p][m];
    for (int i = 0; i < p; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            if (((1 << j) & i) != 0)
                for (int k = 0; k < m; k++)
                    temp[i][k] ^= kernel[j][k];
    return temp;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I enjoy writing stuff like that. Have a good Christmas.

Comment: Thanks ! 

Yep I can see that you're definitely not a beginner :D 

Good Christmas to you too !

Comment: Nice use of `<<` and `^=` for doing base-2 modular arithmetic.