# P^N Combinaisons with Integers (Kernel), how to generate them?

Tags: java, math, complexity-theory, mathematical-optimization, algebra

My question is almost the same that the one I asked few months ago :

[2^N Combinaisons with Integers (Kernel), how to generate them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27642283/2n-combinaisons-with-integers-kernel-how-to-generate-them/27642602?noredirect=1#comment43703976_27642602)

Basically, I wanted to have the 2^N combinaisons inside a Kernel, but I generalized my version, and now it's even more complicated :

I don't want the sum (modulo 2) of every possible combinaisons of 2 elements anymore, but I need now the sum (modulo P) of every possible combinaisons of P elements :O.

```
 N : the number of elements in kernel.
 M : the length of an element in the kernel.
 P : the dimension of my result.

 int[][] Kernel: 

        ....
        i   : 0 1 2 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 2 1 1 2 0 1 2 1 0 2 1 1 2  (length = M)
        i+1 : 1 2 1 0 1 2 0 2 0 1 0 1 2 0 2 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 2 0 1  (length = M)
        ....
        N   : ....

 with P = 3 (so value inside Kernel elements equals to {0,1,2}
```

My Goal (like the previous one with 2^N combinaisons) is to generate all the possibilities (all the P^N combinaisons) who will be like :

```
1 * Kernel[0]
2 * Kernel[0]
....
P * kernel[0]
......
1 * Kernel[0] + 1 * Kernel[1]
1 * Kernel[0] + 2 * Kernel[1]
......
1 * kernel[0] + (P-1) * Kernel[1]
......
1 * kernel[0] + 1 * Kernel[1] ....(P elements) + 1 * Kernel[P]
```

I for now, used the version given by @pbabcdefp
by it works only for sum of 2 elements (modulo 2) and I don't know how to make it works for the sum of P elements (modulo P)

```
public static boolean[][] combinations(boolean kernel[][]) {
    int n = kernel.length;
    int m = kernel[0].length;
    int p = 1 << n;
    boolean[][] temp = new boolean[p][m];
    for (int i = 0; i < p; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            if (((1 << j) & i) != 0)
                for (int k = 0; k < m; k++)
                    temp[i][k] ^= kernel[j][k];
    return temp;
}
```

As again with the previous version, don't mind the memory cost and don't mind the complexity of such array's generation, it's just for a theory case.

Thanks in advance for anyone who has an idea on how to generalize such combinaison.

Best regards,

---

Just in case:  an Example

```
int[][] Kernel : 

      [0] : 0 1 2 0 2 1 2 0
      [1] : 1 2 2 0 1 2 2 0

so we have : N equals to 2 ; M equals to 8 and P equals to 3 (values are included inside {0,1,2}
The result should be : 

 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 (the null element is always inside the result)

 0 1 2 0 2 1 2 0 (1x [0] % 3)
 1 2 2 0 1 2 2 0 (1x [1] % 3)
 0 2 1 0 1 2 1 0 (2x [0] % 3)
 2 1 1 0 2 1 1 0 (2x [1] % 3)
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 (3x [0] % 3)
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 (3x [1] % 3)
 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 (1x [0] + 1x [1] % 3)
 1 1 0 0 2 1 0 0 (2x [0] + 1x [1] % 3)
 2 2 0 0 1 2 0 0 (1x [0] + 2x [1] % 3)
```

We used to have 2 elements inside the kernel, 
we know have P^2 so 3^2 = 9 elements in the new kernel, and we just generate them (except so calcul mistake :D sorry in advance but the calcul is written :D)

Comment: @http://stackoverflow.com/users/3973077/pbabcdefp I summon the master =D if you have any ideas on how to generalize your method :D

Comment: Just so I'm clear on this, the "Kernel" vectors are specified by the user, and the kernel vectors can be any arbitrary vector with integer elements from 0 to P-1?

Comment: Well, to be honest, the kernel vector is calculate by an other functions :) 

but let's say it's arbitrary vector with integer elements between 0 and (P-1) :) The other function doesn't have any influence for the combinaison ;)

So yep, can be N elements, and all of them are random between 0 and (P-1)

Comment: Also, in your example, you also need to mention the `2x [0] + 2x [1] %3` case, correct? At any rate, interesting problem.

Comment: yes indeed, every combinaisons with a coefficient < P ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mathematically, this corresponds to finding all linear combinations of the kernel vectors using all possible sets of coefficients that are `n`-tuples `mod p`. It amounts to a matrix multiplication `mod p` between a `p^n x n` coefficient matrix and a `n x m` kernel matrix.

The `p^n x n` matrix is just a row-wise list of all base-`p` numbers up to `p^n-1`.

I'm afraid I don't know Java that well, so here is the answer in C, which is probably close enough for you to copy and translate from.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h> 

int main() {
  int p = 3; // base
  int n = 2, m = 8;   
  int kernel[2][8] = {{0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 1, 2, 0},
                      {1, 2, 2, 0, 1, 2, 2, 0}};

  int numRows = pow(p,n);
  int coeffs[numRows][n]; 
  int result[numRows][m]; 

  //convert the row numbers from base-10 to base-p   
  int num, row, q, div, remainder;
  for(row=0; row<numRows; row++) {
    num = row;
    for(q=n-1; q>=0; q--) {
      div = (int)pow(p,q);
      remainder = num % div;
      coeffs[row][q] = (num-remainder)/div;
      num = remainder;
    }
  }

  // now do the matrix multiplication
  int i,j,k;
  for(i=0; i<numRows ; i++) {
      for(j=0; j<m ; j++) {
          result[i][j] = 0;
          for(k=0; k<n; k++) {
              result[i][j] += coeffs[i][k]*kernel[k][j];
          }
          result[i][j] %= p;  // take result mod p
          printf("%d ",result[i][j]);
      }
      printf("\n");
  }

}
```

I get the following output:

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 1 2 0 2 1 2 0 
0 2 1 0 1 2 1 0 
1 2 2 0 1 2 2 0 
1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 
1 1 0 0 2 1 0 0 
2 1 1 0 2 1 1 0 
2 2 0 0 1 2 0 0 
2 0 2 0 0 0 2 0
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for :) thank you so much @eigenchris ! :)

and indeed C and Java are basically the same, I will manage :)

Comment: @ValentinMontmirail Glad you found it useful. Out of curiosity, is this being used for something in particular? Or is it just a mathematical curiosity?

Comment: Well :D it's for something quite funny, we found with a mathemical friend that there is an algebra way to solve the generalized version of the http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lights_Out_%28game%29.

So instead of 5*5 with 2 colors :) we now have N*M with P colors :) and our solution + one element in the Kernel can give us a new solution. With all linear combinaisons we now have all the possible solution in this game, so the optimal one (in number of pressed light) ;)

Comment: @ValentinMontmirail Very intriguing! I have often wondered about a mathematical solution to that game. I had never thought about using linear algebra to describe it in this way. Awesome!

Comment: Thanks ;) we will sooner or later write a little something about this in a paper ;) I will try to come back here and to post you the link about our work if you feel interested ;)

Because the vision of this method coded gives us a lot of interesting results, results impossible to obtains just by theoretical mathematics :)

Comment: @ValentinMontmirail Sure. I'd be interested if you remember to post the link.

Comment: i will remember for sure ;) after all :P you put a little something in this project with your StackOverFlow answer ;) 

Thanks again !

Comment: Come to think of it, I think I have thought about this problem before. It just didn't hit me until now because "light's out" is on a 2D grid rather than a 1D grid (which is irrelevant, really). The solution ends up just being a matrix inversion problem `Ax=b`, correct? `A` would be your kernel matrix (it would be square if you use all the lights), `b` would be the "on" lights, and `x` would be the switches you need to hit in order to turn them off?

Comment: You get it ;) that's exactly the goal :). 

With this representation, it allows N*M and not only 5*5 cases, it allows holes in the middle and we can choose to want something different from "every switch shut down" at the end :) 

So with different colors it creates games like "you have first of all, a French flag, there is some rules to go from one color to another, try to change the board into the Italian flag", this kind of things :P 

and there is some rules on the matrix that determined if what we want at the end is possible, etc... ;)